# How to display the label and value attributes as the label in a jsp

Tags: html, jsp, struts, label, key-value

I am using the below code to display a branchlist.

```
<html:option value="">--Select Branch--</html:option>
<html:optionsCollection name="branchList" label="label" value="key"/>
```

How can i display both the branch label and the branch value in the label. for example: right now it displays the label as "Seattle" and the value is "SEA". i want the value to remain the same but the label to be displayed as "Seattle (SEA)"

Also, this is a part of a jsp.
update: The application uses struts framework.

Comment: That's not recognizable as standard JSP. You're using some proprietary MVC framework which offers taglibs for usage in JSP, such as Struts. Please edit the question accordingly to include information about the framework used.

Comment: Yes sir. It uses struts. "branchlist" is being passed from an action class.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following method to you bean:

```
public String getDisplayedLabel() {
    return label + "(" + key + ")";
}
```

and use

```
<html:optionsCollection name="branchList" label="displayedLabel" value="key"/>
```